# How to write log function in c++

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to write the log function in my program. I found this on cplusplus.com:

```
/* log example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>       /* log */

int main ()
{
  double param, result;
  param = 5.5;
  result = log (param);
  printf ("log(%f) = %f\n", param, result );
  return 0;
}
```

This calculates the log of 5.5 to be: 1.704708.
When I put the log of 5.5 into my calculate I get: .740362.
Why is this code giving incorrect values?

Answer (score 5):

`log (5.5)` is **log with base 10** and is equal to 0.740362.

You are looking for the **Natural log** function, ie. with **base e**.

Use the `cmath` header, instead of the `math.h` header for natural log.

```
std::log (5.5); // Gives natural log with base e
std::log10 (5.5); // Gives common log with base 10
```

Read more [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log)

Answer (score 4):

To follow up on what Madhav Datt said, if you are looking for the natural log then rather use the `cmath` header:

- [std::log()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log): *Computes the the natural (base e) logarithm of arg.*
- [std::log10()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log10): *Computes the common (base-10) logarithm of arg.*